# List of Chrome devtool experiments?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I got to `chrome://flags/` on chrome I get a list of options I can turn on.

One of these options is **Developer Tools experiments**. I'm looking for a list which shows all the current dev-tools experiments.

Is there an up to date list somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Version 56.0.2924.87, this is the list I have, found in the Experiments section in Dev Tools Settings

- Accessibility Inspection
- Allow custom UI themes
- Empty sourcemap auto-stepping
- Layers panel
- Live SASS
- Persistence 2.0
- Private script inspection
- Source diff
- Timeline recording perspectives UI
- Track CSS rules usage while recording Timeline

[image: experiments list and version number]